# IGListKit: get the currently visible cell index

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, iglistkit

I am trying to use `IGListKit` ([Link](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit)) in iOS to render custom collection view and table view, where I have a horizontal scrollview in a section controller. In this horizontal scrollview, I need to get the index of the currently visible cells.

I tried to use the `displayDelegate` in the section controller, but it seems to me that the following delegate method is triggered only once when the section controller is initially loaded:

```
func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: IGListAdapter, willDisplay sectionController: IGListSectionController, cell: UICollectionViewCell, at index: Int)
```

So I was wondering if there's a way in `IGListKit` to get the index of the currently visible cells. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use salutations: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 2):

Did you checked IGListAdapter's Visible Objects and Visible SectionController functions?

https://instagram.github.io/IGListKit/Classes/IGListAdapter.html#/c:objc(cs)IGListAdapter(im)visibleSectionControllers

Answer (score 0):

`self.section` provides the index of currently visible cell.